# how to mute microphone in android by java programming

Tags: android, qt, record, microphone, mute

I am working on project that needs to mute the android microphone to avoiding record audio by any other apps.
I'm trying to googling and i found how to mute microphone but the articles just mute the microphone on during a call
code :

```
AudioManager audM = (AudioManager) m_instance.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audM.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

I need an article to mute the microphone on device that other apps can not record at all.
please help me to do that

Comment: Mohsen & Ibrahim, this question is incorrectly tagged for "qt", I believe this should not be so and suggest you remove this incorrect tag.

Answer (score 0):

Android [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), provides all methods needed to play with mic. but your question has to do with a "global" hardware setup - not inside your app - so if Android OS does not provide that functionality, I think the only think you can do is directly blocking the mic to other apps, or block other apps while your code executes .. did you search APIs that does that ?

As for below thread, it seems that if your app initializes the mic, it wont be available for other apps to use it, I didn't check that.

Here is the thread:
[How to block the mic for another app to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418364/how-to-block-the-mic-for-another-app-to-use)