# Get Notification when an app is going to use microphone in Android

Tags: android, microphone, audiorecord

We are doing development in android system. Now we have a service that occupies the microphone so that other apps can't use microphone, such as wechat and so on. Who has a method that can let me get notification when other app wants to use microphone?

Comment: Are you talking about the run time permissions?

Comment: Similar question on stack overflow asked see here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418364/how-to-block-the-mic-for-another-app-to-use)